# Tikz text ragged left in a path

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, tikz-path

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (11,0) -- (18,1) node [midway, sloped, align=left] (sentence) {This is a sentence};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And the corresponding rendering:

[image: Rendering]

So, how to make the text flushleft in the first node of the path?

Comment: `[at start, sloped, right, inner xsep=0pt]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\rlap` together with `pos=0`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (11,0) --node [pos=0, sloped] (sentence) {\rlap{This is a sentence}} (18,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (11,0) --node [pos=0.25, sloped,fill=white] (sentence) {This is a sentence} (18,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

with the following output:

[image]